# uploading a file to my website

Tags: c#, .net

I've seen lots of these questions around here but for some reason I just cant get any to work.. i've spent about 3 hours trying everything I could find and modifying it but to no success. This the form on my website:

```
<form action="http://site.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input name="upfile" type="file" size="100">
<input name="submit" type="submitfile" size="100" value="submit file">

<input type="checkbox" name="submitpublic">
"The file will be visible to anyone"
</form>
```

I need also to check the checkbox, by default it's not checked. I would post the url to my website but it's not hosted yet, I'm looking for a good hosting provider that accepts file sharing (embedded question guys ;) )

Comment: Have you setup a IIS Virtual Directory? *Normally we dont answer [shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) however you could try Peer1 hosting or one I use is WH4L.*

Comment: If you want to take the `HttpWebRequest` route (basically simulating a web browser in your program), there's a question that was asked [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data), and there's also a nice blog post [over here](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2009/12/16/posting-multipartform-data-using-.net-webrequest.aspx)

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson , it's a file sharing website.. another one on the net :p Ichabod Clay I downloaded fiddler and had  look at what was going on after clicking post, I assume I can replicate the whole process using httpwebrequest class so off i go with that :)